# ¿por qué me da el error KeyError: 'frozenset({10303337, 11538037}) en la generación de reglas de asociación?

Tags: python, machine-learning

hola gente quisiera saber si alguien me puede ayudar a resolver un problema. Estoy tratando de hacer un analisis de cesta utilizando la libreria mlxtend de python; el problema es que me da este tipo de error y no encuentro como resolverlo.

Verán, cuando asigno 90000 numero de resultados del itemset anterior a la generacion de reglas funciona y me devuelve resultados, pero si le dejo uno mas bajo como 70000, me lanza este error. Si sigo la sugerencia de usar solo el soporte, entonces tambien me funciona, pero el problema es que son varios set de datos que se deben analizar y usar el mismo procedimiento, por lo tanto debe ser comun la configuracion y por eso no puedo colocar el `support_only=True`, debido a que en otros sets o no me genera reglas de asociacion.

Entonces quisiera saber si existe alguna forma de corregir el error, o el unico metodo es seguir a prueba y error a modo de encontrar un valor que estabilice el resultado de todos los set de datos que tengo, por cierto si de algo sirve la base de datos es oracle 12

```
File "C:\xxxx\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\mlxtend\frequent_patterns\association_rules.py", line 181, in association_rules
    sA = frequent_items_dict[antecedent]
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: frozenset({10303337, 11538037})

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\xxxx\basketanalysispython\rules.py", line 52, in generarReglas
    rules = association_rules(frequent_itemsets, metric="lift", min_threshold=1)#,support_only=True)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\xxxx\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\mlxtend\frequent_patterns\association_rules.py", line 192, in association_rules
    raise KeyError(s)
KeyError: 'frozenset({10303337, 11538037})You are likely getting this error because the DataFrame is missing  antecedent and/or consequent  information. You can try using the  `support_only=True` option'
```